# Issue with Filtering Entity Framework data by Calculated Fields

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern, entity-framework-6

Here's a simplified EF Scenerio of my issue:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public byte Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public DateTime CalculatedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return new DateTime(this.Year, this.Month, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a repository pattern to access these objects, which is also implementing a Where(predicate) method that returns an IEnumrable, just like LINQ. it is being used like this:

```
var myClasses = myClassRepo.Where(mc=> mc.ID > 10);
```

this works well and returns the expected objects with all fields, including CalculatedDate. 
HOWEVER, when i try to use the calculated field as part of the predicate like this:

```
var myClasses = myClassRepo.Where(mc=> mc.CalculatedDate == DateTime.Now);
```

I Receive an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I know I can "walkaround" this by retrieving a first set of results, and then filtering it further by the calculated field. but I'm trying to understand why this is happening and  what could be done to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework tries to convert your LINQ to SQL, so it has trouble with trying to convert your MyClass.CalculatedDate method into something recognizable in SQL. You may be able to get around this by adding an .AsEnumerable() call in your LINQ before your where, like so:

```
var myClasses = myClassRepo.AsEnumerable().Where(mc => mc.CalculatedDate == DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: looking at SQL profiler, CalculatedDate doesn't seem to be part of the query. plus, Adding AsEnumerable does not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because EF doesn't support querying on custom properties, as they cannot be translated into a DB column